# How to convert custom post type based list to a dropdown list?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, dropdown, list

I have been created a query to list the post from current taxomony, filt by term slug for my book site (as table of content). And it worked very well. But, is there any way to convert it to a dropdown list? (I'm a newbie)
Here is the code:

```
// Start the list (I want to convert this to dropdown list)
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
while ( $query->have_posts($post->ID) ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="';
    the_permalink();
    echo '">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a></li>';  
endwhile;
// End the list
?>
```

Comment: Instead of putting them on a list, put them in a select, and each item would be an option. With JavaScript, make the selected items redirect on change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the_title()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) and [the_permalink()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) are functions that automatically echoed. Use in this case `get_the_title()` and `get_permalink()`.

the code should look something like this:

```
while ( $query->have_posts($post->ID) ) : $query->the_post();
    echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink(). '">' .get_the_title() .'</a></li>';  
endwhile;
```

Here is another way using `the_title` and `the_permalink`:

```
while ( $query->have_posts($post->ID) ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
   <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile;
```